# I mounted an ISO, but it mounts with 000 permissions, and as a result, I can only access it as root. How can I make it accessible to a normal user?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, iso-image

I mounted an ISO image, and when I tried accessing the mount point, it said "permission denied". I checked with `ls -l`, and the mount point had `d---------` at the beginning, meaning its permission bits are 000. I unmounted it, and then remounted it, this time explicitly specifying the UID/GID and permissions using `-o uid=1000,gid=1000,mode=555`, but the result was the same. The ISO still works in that I can access the files with root privileges, but I need to run something from there as a normal user, not as root. And even if I run it as root, the permissions still cause issues.

I'm aware I could copy everything as root and `chmod -R` it, but it would be nice to have a way to install it straight from the ISO.

So far I've encountered this issue on two different ISO's, both from the same source. In case you want to try and reproduce the issue, they are the [LabVIEW Community Edition](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/labview/select-edition/labview-community-edition.html) ISO's from National Instruments, both the 2020 and NXG versions. I want to try installing it using Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual, `-o mode=` is ineffective when the filesystem itself carries information about file ownership & permissions using the *Rock Ridge* format extensions.

(It could be that the publisher thought they were specifying 0 as the mode *mask* while generating the ISO image… or that they just enabled Rock Ridge by accident, as it's not used by Windows.)

Mount with the **`-o norock`** option to make Linux ignore the additional Rock Ridge data.

Comment: Mounting with `-o norock` worked perfectly—thank you!